# How to use params with special caracter in React with Found router

Tags: reactjs, routes

I'm trying to pass a id like this "CD.PLP.100.2011" as a param for a route, but I get this error: Cannot GET /app/bill/CD.PLP.100.2011. When I remove all the dots it works.

There's any way I can handle this problem?

I know that I can replace the dots by another character before passing the param, but there's any better solution?

My route:

```
<Route path="/bill/:id" Component={Bill}>
```

My problem was with webpack, not with Found library.

I solved following this issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/454

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do url encoding, which will convert the dots. And decode it in the component where we are using it.

Comment: That's the way I don't want to do it haha I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: What's wrong with that solution? URI encoding/decoding is standard practice for special characters.